# How to set the selected item in Alloy UI combo box?

Tags: jsp, liferay

After filling an Alloy UI combo box with items, How can I set the Selected Item?
I mean, one of the items inserted into combo box should be the default selected item. How I can set that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsp:

```
    <aui:select name="selectedCity" label="City:" id="selectedCity">
        <c:forEach items="${cities}" var="city">
            <aui:option value="${city}" label="${city}" selected="${selectedCity == city}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </aui:select>
```

java:

```
    renderRequest.setAttribute("selectedCity", selectedCity);
    List<String> cities = Lists.newArrayList("New Yourk", "Moskau", "London", "Rom");
    renderRequest.setAttribute("cities", cities);
```

Comment: Is id="selectedCity" necessary?